# Configure Windows VM created by VMSS through Bastion Host

Tags: azure, ansible, terraform

I have created my infrastructure through Terraform, the relevant (Azure) resources are

- Application Gateway
- VMSS (Virtual Machine Scale Set)
- Windows VMs => Created/Destroyed by VMSS (Windows VM are in private
  subnet, and HTTPS access is through Application Gateway)
- Ubuntu based Bastion Host (for RDP and ansible configuration)

So far I am able to configure one of my windows VM through Ansible using `psrp` protocol, but that was only possible because I knew the private IPV4 of my VM (added the private IP to host file of bastion vm). How can I do it without knowing the IP address(es)?

My other question is how will the Ansible know a new VM has been created and it needs to be configured?

**Edit**
If you think this is not the best approach, please guide me on how to do it properly? Should I use `Packer` with custom image? OR is there any other option? The main configuration I want to do is enable IIS and install a few programs like GIT.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way IMO is to use a [dynamic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html). Although the doc examples are detailed for clobber and EC2, you will find more info on the [included scripts](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/stable-2.9/contrib/inventory) with examples for Azure.

Once you have your dynamic inventory in place, you can refresh it with [`meta: refresh_inventory`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/meta_module.html#parameter-free_form) whenever you need to.

Comment: hi, thanks I have tried using the dynamic inventory and was able to ping the vms created by the vmss, but problem remains that i need to get private ip addresses of those vms, that needs to added to `host` of bastion vm. or is there any other way of doing this without adding ips of windows vm in bastion vm `host`?

Comment: Unless there is something I totally didn't understand, if you are able to ping those machines with the dynamic inventory, you are able to gather facts on those machine and therefore list any IP configured on those hosts.

Comment: @Zeitounator I suspect a double interface in the OP infra where there is a public IP for production data and a private IP for management

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε ansible should report both in gathered facts, unless of course it is not possible to login with or become a privileged user on the "public" ip. In which case this is becoming hard to solve.

Comment: I am wondering if Azure is not publishing some VPC internal DNS on the Bastion that could be accessible in the dynamic inventory over all this. And that the OP could have the data but not in an "expected" form? Just basing this on my AWS knowledges, I am not used to Azure.